# C++ Replace dynamic objects in vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I'm wondering if I replace a dynamically allocated object in a vector with another, does the object get deleted or do I have to do it myself?

```
vector<thingamajig*> myvec;

... 

myvec[17] = new thingamajig(paramsA);

...

myvec[17] = new thingamajig(paramsB); //what happens to the previous thingamajig?
```

Is this a memory leak?  I don't understand vectors well enough to know if it'll delete thingamajig(paramsA) automatically or not.  If not what is the proper way to clean the old one up?

Comment: It acts the same as normal, meaning you leak since you didn't delete. If you use `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` assignment will not leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what happens to the previous thingamajig

You lost the pointer to previous `myvec[17]` thus causes memory leak.

You'd better use smart pointer in `std::vector`

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<thingamajig>> myvec;

myvec[17].reset(new thingamajig(paramsB));
```